# Unit Testing Angular Function using Karma Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a function like this inside a controller

```
$scope.closeMenu = function () {
                    $('#menu').hide();
                };
```

If a functions returns a value I am able to test using
expect($scope.value).toEqual();
How do we test the above function using jasmine. Please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a functions returns a value I am able to test using expect($scope.value).toEqual(); How do we test the above function using jasmine

You should rewrite your function, so as it only set a variable of the model. Then it will be testable using the way you already know in Jasmine. One of the point of angular is that you don't manipulate the DOM from the controller. Providing you follow these guidelines, controllers are far easier to test.

Moreover, in your case rewriting is very straightforward:

```
$scope.closeMenu = function () {
    $scope.isOpen = false;
};
```

Template:

```
... id="menu" ng-show="isOpen" ...
```

---

In case you still need to test some characteristics of a DOM element, for example it's visibility, [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) might be useful for you. Example:

```
expect($('#menu')).toBeHidden()
```

Comment: For the code I have is it impossible to write unit test? I do not want to change the code and trying to figure out a way to test this

Comment: Sure it's possible, but not with Jasmine. You would need some addition to it.

Comment: May I know what is the addition needed?

Comment: [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) for example. Then an expectation like `expect($('#menu')).toBeHidden()` would be possible.

Comment: thanks.. I got to know how to solve my problem but I am having issues in using jasmine-jquey.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248952/using-jasmine-jquery